# Linker command failed with exit code 1 after installing CocoaPods and firebase pod

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I'm trying to use the firebase pod, however getting this (see image) error message when a run is attempted.

I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202255/pod-install-bash-pod-command-not-found) to install Cocoapods and added the firebase dependency to the Podfile.

p.s I tried to clean it a bunch of times.

[image]

Comment: Are you running the `xcworkspace` project file? If yes, try to restart Xcode and then clean your project before running it.

Comment: No, I'm not. the guide said to simply close xcode then `instal pods` but now i'm thinking about I remember you have to open a new project file created by pods right?

Comment: Yes you do to be able to access the pod files. Try it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Try to add `pod 'Firebase'` to your pod file and reinstall pod after that.

Comment: I open the `xcworkspace` project file and it just opens the `xcodeproj` file. is that normal?

Comment: No, you must run the xcworkspace app.

Comment: Well that we really strange, I closed xcode and reopened it and it then decided to forget the error and all it working fine.. lol

Comment: Check my first comment to restart Xcode :) But good that it´s working.

Comment: @RashwanL  : Not worked for me. I am using xcode 8.3.3

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I got stuck for awhile trying to solve this, but the solution turned out to be very easy :)
If you are using *`Cocoapods`* in your project, one needs to use *`xcworkspace`* to build instead of *`xcproject`*. 
If you are using  *`Cocoapods`* and build from  *`xcproject`* , it will ignore the *`Cocoapods`* libraries you need.

Comment: Mine problem solved after running the application through ".xcworkspace" instead of ".xcodeproj"

Comment: For those who don't know how to build workspace instead of xcode project, here is the step. Open your xcode project in FINDER and the project contains ".xcworkspace" and ".xcodeproj", double click .xcworkspace file to open. That's it.

Comment: sir i have already i used xcworkspace but not working for me tell m any other way to fix above error?

Comment: Hi @Kapilsoni, hope your issue has been fixed. There is nothing that I can add here. I just suggest one more time to review your steps to see if there is something missing.

Comment: @HamidHoseini yes sir my issue has been fixed but after change build setting to legacy build system then after clean and archive error is gone.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes its because of you might be declaring an object with same variable name.

Clear the repeating variable name change it. After that clean your project and build again.
Its worked for me....! Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about in one class or different class? If one class we cannot have object with same name. If different class how come it affect each other?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem for hours and solved it with a simple hack. Just do **clean** and then **Build**

Answer (score 2):

This error will also trigger when several components (files) with identical names were added to Xcode workspace.

Renaming them will fix this error.

Comment: how do I know which file is identical?

Comment: @YusufKhan In my case, I had import duplicates. You can start simply by opening the files tree in the Xcode' workspace and see if you have identical files (some of them might be highlighted in red if missing).

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but what did the trick for me were cmd + q xcode, navigate to project folder, `pod update`, reopen open the `.xcworkspace` file, clean project and run/build again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes occurs when you perform an invalid delete through *`cocoapods`*.

In my case I installed a framework through *`cocoapods`* which required bitcode set to **"enabled"**, later when I longer needed it removed it from *`Podfile`* and `pod install`.

That's when encountered this error, solving it by setting the required targets to **"disabled"** in bitcode option.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error when  I was trying to configure cellIdentifiers in different Controllers.

I declared two variables globally with the same name. To solve this error I just renamed the second variable.

```
#import "ResultsTableViewController.h"

NSString *const kNormalCellidentifierName = @"NormalStoryCelll";

@interface ResultsTableViewController ()


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because the pod that I was using used Swift and I didn't include the `use_frameworks!` line in my podfile.

I didn't include that line before and therefore had to create a Swift file in my project and a [Objective-C bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift) (which Apple offers to do for you the first time you add a swift file to your project).

If you told it not to create the bridge, then you can use this guys [tutorial](https://mycodetips.com/ios/manually-adding-swift-bridging-header-1290.html) to manually create it as well as the settings needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot to fix this issue and failed for every attempt.

Then i just simply used:

```
pod install
```

and to my surprise, simply it solved my issue.