# How to fix swift linker error "framework not found GTMSessionFetcher clang"

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podfile, gtmsessionfetcher

This error suddenly showed up in my Swift program

> ld: framework not found GTMSessionFetcher
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

but I have it as one of the frameworks
[image]

and this is the pod file

[image]

I have remove cocoapods and reinstalled it and no result

I have clean and open the workspace instead of the project and still no changes.

I have tried all approaches from similar questions and still no luck. 
some of the answers I've looked at are
[Apple Mach-O Linker Warning "Directory Not Found For Option..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772151/apple-mach-o-linker-warning-directory-not-found-for-option)

[Linker command failed with exit code 1 after installing CocoaPods and firebase pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115708/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-after-installing-cocopods-and-firebase-po)

https://www.bountysource.com/issues/39247126-clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-vto-see-invocation

I noticed my error is somewhat unique to what I have been seeing from others in that it's a GTMSessionFetcher error.
How can I fix this and get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1):

First, try running `pod install`.

It looks like `GTMSessionFetcher.framework` is grayed out, which means that the file was deleted. If `pod install` doesn't work, try removing each grayed-out framework file from the list and dragging it back in (either from the project folder or from the sidebar under "Products").

Comment: i tired both option and still not changes

Comment: When you tried the second option, was it still grayed out after?

Comment: When I say "remove it from the list", I mean select the grayed-out framework and click the "-" icon. Make sure that's what you're doing. Also, where are you dragging the frameworks back in from? Have you checked your build phases (especially "Target Dependencies" and "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks")?

Comment: yes I did just that. I removed the file from the folder below and run pod install which reinstalled the folder

Comment: Where are you dragging the framework files themselvess back in from? Have you checked your build phases (especially "Target Dependencies" and "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks")?

Comment: projectTest and projectUITest are the only dependencies there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161344/discussion-between-coder256-and-learner101).

Comment: the chat timed out