# React Native Image Picker cannot read property "showImagePicker" of undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I've followed all of the iOS installation instructions for the package `react-native-image-picker`, but it still errors any time I try to use the `showImagePicker()` method.

It tells me it `cannot read property "showImagePicker" of undefined`.

I have the package imported at the top of my file `var ImagePicker = require('react-native-image-picker');`, I have done `react-native link` multiple times, I have added `RNImagePicker.xcodeproj` to my libraries folder, I have added `RNImagePicker.a` to "Link Binary with Libraries", I have added the permissions to my `info.plist` file.

I have done everything in the documentation, but still nothing works.

Here is my JS:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ScrollView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';

var ImagePicker = require('react-native-image-picker');

export default class ProfilePicUploaderPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ProfilePicLocalSource: null,
    ProfilePicRemoteSource: null
  }

  ChoosePhoto(){
    console.log(SOCButton);
    var options = {
      title: 'Select Avatar',
      customButtons: [
        {name: 'fb', title: 'Choose Photo from Facebook'},
      ],
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images'
      }
    };
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      }
      else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      }
      else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      }
      else {
        let source = { uri: response.uri };

        this.setState({
          avatarSource: source
        });
      }
    });


  }

  render(){
      return(<all of my JSX>);
  }
```

The only lead I have as to what's happening is that when I try to build my app in Xcode, it fails with the error `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

Comment: why are you using `this.ImagePicker` instead of only `ImagePicker`? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @MamdohSaraireh sorry that was a mistake. When I was debugging myself I thought that might fix my issue. I edited the question.

Comment: Did you use cocoapods on the project?

Comment: @hawkup yes I did

Comment: I'm not sure. check this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47114775/1754750).

Comment: run the commands **react-native run-ios** and **react-native run-andriod**

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have imported ImagePicker into your JS file. Try using `import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker'`

If you've followed the linking steps correctly for iOS you should be good.