# Xcode 9.2: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods, xcode9

I installed Cocoapods. I used GoogleMaps. When I build workspace on my device i get this error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2n1l.png)
I also tried all this instructions: [Linker command failed with exit code 1 after installing CocoaPods and firebase pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115708/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-after-installing-cocoapods-and-firebase-p)
P.S. Building on simulator works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you've already check if you've open the .xcworkspace created in your project folder.(NOT .xcodeproj)

If still doesn't work try

- Go to Project Settings.
- Go to Build Settings.
- Change BUILD ACTIVE
- ARCHITECTURE ONLY to NO.

Comment: I tried to build it on my ios 10.3 device, it was my problem. The GoogleMaps pods is for ios 11. Thank you!