# Unity SDK Xcode build failure due to WebView usage

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, webview

I use Unity SDK to build iOS app with Branch.io support. Xcode build failed with error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WKWebView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BNCUserAgentCollector.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CSSearchableItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BranchCSSearchableItemAttributeSet.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CSSearchableItemAttributeSet", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BranchCSSearchableItemAttributeSet in BranchCSSearchableItemAttributeSet.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CSSearchableIndex", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BranchCSSearchableItemAttributeSet.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CSSearchableItemAttributeSet", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_BranchCSSearchableItemAttributeSet in BranchCSSearchableItemAttributeSet.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Apple deprecated WebView recently.

Comment: Hi Alex, please try this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365354/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-duplicate-symbol-tmrbbp/47971886

Comment: You wrote deprecated "_recently_", but it was [more than two years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46165912/1033581).